# PHP SimpleXMLElement not parsing <title> node

Tags: php, xml, title, xmlnode

I have a simple well-formed XML doc that I'm writing to the page using PHP. For some reason the output never includes the title node, and after researching I can't figure this out. If I change the title node to 'heading' or some other name it is included in the output, but when its named 'title', this node is skipped.

Here's the XML doc code...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <items>
        <product>
            <id>cd1</id>
            <title>CD One</title>
            <description>This is my first CD</description>
            <img>/images/sample.jpg</img>
            <price>14.99</price>
        </product>
    </items>
```

The PHP code looks like this...

```
    <?php
    $filename = '../catalog.xml';

    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);

    echo $contents;
    ?>
```

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried reading it with SimpleXML to see if you get a similar result?

Comment: Yes. Same result. I just installed WAMP on my machine. Do you think it might be a PHP configuration issues?

Comment: Also, I'm using NetBeans 7.1 as my IDE. I'm new with this software, so that might be part of the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the XML you posted is not valid XML;

The encoding should be in lowercase. Try with this string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <items>
        <product>
            <id>cd1</id>
            <title>CD One</title>
            <description>This is my first CD</description>
            <img>/images/sample.jpg</img>
            <price>14.99</price>
        </product>
    </items>
```

Validate here: http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: It did validate, and the example for utf-8 encoding declaration for XML is in caps on W3Schools...http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp

Comment: Thanks though, I gave it a try anyway. No dice.

Comment: Did it work? Because I think there must have been whitespace somewhere in your declaration. . .

Comment: This was a blatant error on my part. I noticed that the <title> node contents were being placed in the browser tab. The issue was that I did not have the proper <html> on the page as I was just trying to test this code. Once I added the HTML, and parsed through the XML with SimpleXML its working fine. Thank.

Comment: Glad you found your solution! We like SO members who are actively working on solutions to their own problems.